# Is it acceptable to open a modal popup on top of another modal popup?

Tags: web, popup, modal-windows

**On the web, is it wise to allow a modal popup (B) to be opened from another modal popup (A)?**

If modal popup B were to be closed, the user would again be viewing modal popup A.

I am asking as I can envisage some issues e.g. with dismissing the second popup, if the overlay is clicked do both modals close or just the second one? Would the user think that the first modal has gone or would they know they can return to it by closing the second modal? etc.

**Example mockup:**

1. Modal A.
   [image]
2. Modal B. Opens when 'button' is clicked in Modal A
   [image]

Comment: In what situation should this be needed? I'm curious.

Comment: You could just change the content of the first popup (or hide it and show the new without the user notice) to avoid the possible confusion.. Like Stackexchange "Flag" popups.

Comment: I agree with many of the comments in this chain.  I would just add that it also depends on the actions you're asking the user to perform. Depending, there are other ways of handling actions that may not require another modal, such as inline editing or the like: http://thevectorlab.net/flatlab/inline_editor.html

Comment: Avoid popups as much as possible https://developer.appway.com/screen/ShowSingleRecipe/selectedRecipeId/1390246496349

Comment: A detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/bootstrap-modal-window-close-current-open-new-modal/

Comment: @PaulvandenDool say you had a finance database application. You have a modal to create a new invoice, within which the user needs to select a customer. The user realises that the customer record hasn't yet been created, so clicks an "add" button to launch a modal to create the customer record, after which they return to the invoice creation modal (with customer now populated) and continue their work. There's no break in workflow. This flow is fairly common in enterprise applications.

Comment: @angularrocks.com idk, some of the stuff in that article seems a little off base. It says "modal windows are discouraged in user interface design, because they interrupt users and force them into doing a specific action". Modals only interrupt the user if they are opened without the user's consent. If a user initiates an action that opens the modal (meaning they want the modal to open so they can do something), then the modal isn't interrupting anything at all, it's just doing what the user wants. A more valid reasoning would be that including modals increases the number of total clicks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In general, I use the following guidelines for using modals:

**Is it focused?** Every time you throw a modal in front of a user, you're disrupting their workflow. Disruption isn't always bad. Sometimes that's what you want. But you have to realize you're doing that and use it for your benefit. Items within a modal should self-contained. A good rule of thumb is that a modal should be used only when it's content is focused or can be shown on it's own page. Examples of this are **Pinterest** cards, **Trello** pins, or **Behance** posts. Notice that they're all self-contained posts, which can be deep-linked to, but all use modals in-line to focus the user's attention on one specific item. The user doesn't have to remember other items in order to interact with it.

**Is it consistent?** Without clear guidelines for when and how items like modals can be used, they can lose their effectiveness because they'll be used all over the place. Unfortunately a poor example of this is right here at **Stack Exchange.** On your user profile, your top-level menu contains links to "Edit • Privileges • Preferences • Flair •  Apps", all of which take you other pages. The last item in that list, "My Logins", opens in a modal. This isn't consistent with how modals are used elsewhere to alert the user or help them focus on a task.

**Is it overly complex?** Using a modal on top of another modal is a big red flag that something broke down in your workflow. If your workflow requires a second modal, you probably have some bigger issues with complexity within your modal. Remember: some of the best use cases for modals are focused, simple content. **Squarespace** use multiple modals for when you add certain content. And while I love the product, this is the item I hate the most in the product. It's confusing and tedious.

Modals are a great tool. Their overuse can blunt their effectiveness in your workflow, though.

Comment: I'm consistenly putting discrete things into focus. Why? Because giving focus helps, when things are complex. But the whole thing shouldn't be *overly* complex, right? Because then I will have "bigger issues with complexity within my modals". I'm not sure if these guidelines can help me. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 9):

No never. Adding a second modal dialog over the first one is the equivalent of using pop-up window over pop-up window (and there's a good reason they where blocked in the browser and soon deprecated in web design). Instead try to guide your users through a modal dialog wizard with clear interface of what to expect next. User feel comfortable and trust the application when she knows what to expect next. Like the following example:

[image]

> ## What
>
> Lead the user through the interface step by step to do tasks in a prescribed order.
>
> ## Use when
>
> You are designing a UI for a task that is long or complicated, and that will usually be novel for users—not something that they do often or want much fine-grained control over (such as the installation of a software package). You’re reasonably certain that the designer of the UI will know more than the user does about how best to get the task done.

Reference: [Designing Interfaces: Wizard](http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/wizard/)

[image]

Comment: I agree 99%, but I think with a very pragmatic approach it could be done if the modals are 'upgraded' to cards and stacked, just like in the LinkedIn application for iPad. http://a2.mzstatic.com/eu/r30/Purple/v4/de/0a/a1/de0aa15a-f0ce-5803-cba0-c7eb8b0842e0/screen480x480.jpeg - of course this is touch, but I believe this pattern should be possible to port to web as well. But anyway, the question is: are they still modals?

Comment: @DominikOslizlo I Think they are since they block user from editing anything else, which is what a modal view do.

Comment: "No never" sounds too limiting to me. Of course, modals should be used sparingly, but if they make sense, why not use them? I don't think your comparison to pop up windows is right, the problem of pop up windows is something completely different. So, I don't disagree that you should reconsider what you're doing if you get that second modal, but I don't agree with your reasoning.

Comment: @BennySkogberg Yes but what about confirmation messages? For example lets say we have a modal for editing an item and it includes a delete button, a delete confirmation modal on this case IMO is considered good practice or atleast not bad practice

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Do you have to confirm a delete? I would much rather hav a UI where I'm in control and not being asked to confirm all the time. It's better to implement a visible undo button after deletion or implement at waste basket from where you can retreive wrongly deleted items.

Comment: I believe confirming deletion is always necessary as much as deletion undo. Personal opinion though.

Answer (score 3):

Modal windows are used when you want to create some form of dependency i.e stop user from doing other work until what is required in the modal is complete. If modal 2 could open from modal 1, it wouldn't be any different from the pop-up windows. So in my opinion, closing one modal to view another modal should be avoided in the first place. For any technical reason, if modal 2 overlays on modal 1, it should be seamless i.e. user shouldnt see two different modals. Closing modal 2 should close modal 1...imho.

It would need to be a different design just incase you want some kind of comparison/references between multiple windows.

Answer (score 2):

A modal window is an added layer of complexity, distilled from the level below. If you add another layer your adding another layer of complexity (no matter how much content your layer contains).

What you are doing here is forcing the user to built *your* mental model and not her *own*.