# Opening a modal popup on top of another

Tags: responsive-design

I understood that opening a modal popup on top of another is not a good practice and a good ux, but my project has the same requirement. I have a modal popup which contains the list of stores with a link to the map and upon clicking on the map link, another modal need to be appear and the previous modal popup with list of stores should still remain open and blurred. Upon closing the second modal, the first should be active again. Below is the page which exactly depicts my requirement, but I am not sure what is the best way to achieve this. Can someone please help ??

[Is it acceptable to open a modal popup on top of another modal popup?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52042/is-it-acceptable-to-open-a-modal-popup-on-top-of-another-modal-popup)

Thank you,
Prakash.

Comment: Are you asking _how_ to open a modal popup on top of another or whether you should?

Comment: @norabora This seems like a question on *how* to do it, which requires understanding knowledge about the code for the design. If this question was clarified it would likely need to be migrated to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that you should try to avoid opening a modal on top of another modal, but if you have to do it it's very simple. Simply have the first modal display with a link on that modal somewhere that would open up the second modal, **but do not make the second modal the same size make sure it is smaller and fits within the first modal** so that the user can see that they still have the first modal in the background. I would also make sure you have an **close button on the second modal** so that they can navigate back to the first modal. In addition it may be a good idea to have the second modal close if the user clicks on modal 1 in the background, making it much easier for the user to navigate between the two. If you're going to practice incorrect UX be sure to do it as effectively as possible and make it easy on the user. Just some suggestions, hope they help.